# Cube with independent faces explode and rotate?

Tags: transforms, keyframes

This is another newb question but I've run out of ideas.

Create a default cube, separate all 6 faces out into individual objects.

Edit: I want to key frame all six faces to to rotate X 180

However, I also want each face to move "out" (along it's normal to face direction) by 0.5 at X=90deg rotation and back to 0.0 at 180deg rotation.

If I keyframe the Z for example on the top face, as it rotates it does funky things because the Z is relative to world and not the latest position of the face.

I want all faces to "explode" about the centre / origin / world centre and com back to a closed cube at the end of the rotation animation.

So in my head I want to keyframe the face movement relative to an axis that is ALSO rotating?

Images are start position, blue ish face on top.
90 deg rotation around X faces "exploded" by 0.5, blue face now facing left
Finish position "collapsed back" with blue face now pointing down.

Last image is at 45deg X rotation where you can see the faces are going TO their mid rotation position FROM their start position and not expanding OUT from the centre of the box. It is this behaviour I want to rectify.

Any help much appreciated.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cloud you sketch your design or add reference so we can see the picture.

Comment: I've edited my initial and added screenshots.

Comment: usually you would have each face as a separate object but parented to an empty, then keyframe position for the planes and then keyframe rotation for the empty... but it can be done in a dozen of ways, if I understand what you mean this could be just a rotating cube with an edge split modifier and an animated displace modifier

Comment: I just ran a test on "rotating cube with an edge split modifier and an animated displace modifier" and it is EXACTLY the result I want. Many thanks!!

Comment: cool, maybe write an answer to your own question then? don't know if it's fine though

Comment: Is that the approved "closing" process here?